# Create a Multi-Index Pandas Dataframe, add rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a multi-index dataframe. Multi-Index for the columns. Then I want to insert 0 filled rows into the dataframe.

Here's my code so far:

```
tuples = [('Calculus', 'Jenny'), ('Calculus', 'Tom'),
          ('Geography', 'Steve'), ('Geography', 'Michael')]

df = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=('Class', 'Student'))
df
```

It's unclear to me if Class and Student are the columns of df. When I run the columns method on df, I get an except indicating that that df doesn't have such a function.

Also, I used some code that I got from another StackOverflow posting to add an all place holder values ('0') row, but this code did not work, either:

```
df.loc[len(df)] = '0'
```

That code returns an AttributeError indicating that the multi-index object does not have a loc attribute.

Comment: Your `df` isn’t a data frame. It’s an index, which is a component of a dataframe. 

Look at the dataframe docstring to see how to create a dataframe based on your index.

Comment: I want class to be level 0 of the column index.

And Student to be level 1.

I tried to add the rough layout to this comment, but it doesn't look exactly like I wrote it.

Comment: OK, I think I see that now. I will modify the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the multi-index for columns
tuples = [('Calculus', 'Jenny'), ('Calculus', 'Tom'),
          ('Geography', 'Steve'), ('Geography', 'Michael')]
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=('Class', 'Student'))

# Create the DataFrame with the multi-index columns
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=multi_index)

# Add a new row with 0-filled values
new_row = pd.Series(0, index=df.columns)
df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

OUTPUT:
Calculus      Geography
Jenny Tom     Steve Michael
0        0   0        0       0

Answer (score 1):

### * EDIT * Column Index Variant

##### (credit [Paul H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552748/paul-h) for the clarification)

Make your first row all zeros with `data = [[0]*len(tuples)]` set the index to `[0]` and the columns to your multi-index. You can have multiple rows of 0 value by increasing the idex, e.g. `index = [0, 1, 2]`

```py
tuples = [('Calculus', 'Jenny'), ('Calculus', 'Tom'),
          ('Geography', 'Steve'), ('Geography', 'Michael')]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[0]*len(tuples)], 
                  columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=('Class', 'Student')), 
                  index = [0])
```

Output:

```
Class          Calculus          Geography
Student     Jenny     Tom     Steve   Michael
      0         0       0         0       0
```

---

---

#### Row index variant

1.) As a one liner, you can set your index to that MultiIndex and have your rows filled with 0 and the column be called "fill" by making an array of zeros the length of your tuples:

```py
tuples = [('Calculus', 'Jenny'), ('Calculus', 'Tom'),
          ('Geography', 'Steve'), ('Geography', 'Michael')]

df = pd.DataFrame([0]*len(tuples), columns = ['fill'], 
                  index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=('Class', 'Student')))
```

Output:

```
                    fill
Class      Student  
Calculus     Jenny  0
               Tom  0
Geography    Steve  0
           Michael  0
```

2.) With some more steps to view the process, you can create a dataframe from your tuples and label the columns, then create a new column called "fill" and set every value to 0, and then lastly make your `Class` and `Student` columns the index:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(tuples, columns = ['Class', 'Student'])
df['fill'] = 0
df = df.set_index(['Class', 'Student'])
```

Output:

```
                    fill
Class      Student  
Calculus     Jenny  0
               Tom  0
Geography    Steve  0
           Michael  0
```

Comment: Class and Student are supposed to be levels of the column index

Comment: @PaulH I might be misunderstanding what you mean, Class is level 0 of the index and Student is level 1 of the index.

Comment: Right. And the OP wants this index object to be the column index, not the row index

Comment: @PaulH Ah... yes, thank you for the clarification. I've added the column index variant at the top as an edit.  FYI to OP... Amine Hayani 's answer should be considered as theirs was always a correct solution.